# Kubernetes - Mark Pod completed when container completes

Tags: kubernetes

Let's say I have a `Pod` with 2 containers: `App` and `Database`. I want to run a `Pod` that executes a command in `App` and then terminates.

I have set up my `App` container to run that command, and then it succesully runs and terminates which is great. But now my `Database` container is still running, so the `Pod` is not marked as `complete`.

How can I get the `Pod` to be marked as complete when the `App` container is completed?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a call to the Kubernetes API server to accomplish this. Consider the following example:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: multi-container-completion
spec:
  containers:
    - name: long-running-process
      image: fbgrecojr/office-hours:so-47848488
      command: ["sleep", "1000"]
    - name: short-running-process
      image: fbgrecojr/office-hours:so-47848488
      command: ["sleep", "1"]
      lifecycle:
        preStop:
          exec:
            command: ["/pre-stop.sh"]
```

**`pre-stop.sh`**

```
#!/bin/bash
curl \
  -X DELETE \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" \
  --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt \
  https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local/api/v1/namespaces/$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace)/pods/$HOSTNAME
```

**`Dockerfile` for `fbgrecojr/office-hours:so-47848488`**

```
FROM centos:latest
COPY pre-stop.sh /
RUN chmod +x /pre-stop.sh
```

*NOTE:* I was not able to properly test this because `preStop` hooks do not seem to be working for my local Minikube setup. In case this issue is not localized to me, the corresponding issue can be tracked [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/57289).